# Newbie performance issue with foreach ...need advice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This section simply reads from an excel spreadsheet. This part works fine with no performance issues.

```
IEnumerable<ImportViewModel> so=data.Select(row=>new ImportViewModel{
                  PersonId=(row.Field<string>("person_id")),
                  ValidationResult = ""
                  }).ToList();
```

Before I pass to a View I want to set ValidationResult so I have this piece of code. If I comment this out the model is passed to the view quickly. When I use the foreach it will take over a minute. If I hardcode a value for item.PersonId then it runs quickly. I know I'm doing something wrong, just not sure where to start and what the best practice is that I should be following.

```
foreach (var item in so)
                {
                    if (db.Entity.Any(w => w.ID == item.PersonId))
                    {
                        item.ValidationResult = "Successful";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        item.ValidationResult = "Error:  ";
                    }
                 } 

return View(so.ToList());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like this :

```
var ids = so.Select(i=>i.PersonId).Distinct().ToList();
// Hitting Database just for this time to get all Users Ids
var usersIds = db.Entity.Where(u=>ids.Contains(u.ID)).Select(u=>u.ID).ToList();
foreach (var item in so)
                {
                    if (usersIds.Contains(item.PersonId))
                    {
                        item.ValidationResult = "Successful";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        item.ValidationResult = "Error:  ";
                    }
                 } 

return View(so.ToList());
```

Comment: I'd sugggest to add `.Distinct` to first line.
It whould reduce ammount of data sent to SQL Server.
`var ids = so.select(i=>i.PersonId).Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: Folks, I really appreciate this. Thanks for taking the time to explain how to improve my code. This worked very nicely and it makes a lot of sense. cheers

Answer (score 5):

You are now performing a database call per item in your list. This is really hard on your database and thus your performance. Try to itterate trough your excel result, gather all users and select them in one query. Make a list from this query result (else the query call is performed every time you access the list). Then perform a match between the result list and your excel.